# Using more than one build for a single instance

Tags: java, android, maven

I always like to use build tools for my project like **Maven**. It makes my job much easier. However, I wanted to know if it's possible to use more than one build tool for a single instance of work flow?

Like, can I *configure* the jars in my **pom.xml** file using my **gradle** tool?

I tried doing so, but I arrive at error saying :-

> "can't define your project".

I tried searching for the same but couldn't find an answer. Is it just me or am I missing something important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding Maven, this tool only supports the `pom.xml`, it's not capable in reading other buildtool files. And I think you should just pick one tool which best fits the project or the team. Otherwise you need to keep the files in sync for the different tools and that's a recipe for disaster.